What do traditions say about the post- healing life of Bartimaeus, the blind beggar?
We read in Mark 10:46-47

As Jesus was leaving Jericho with his disciples and a sizable crowd,
Bartimaeus, a blind man, the son of Timaeus,
sat by the roadside begging.
On hearing that it was Jesus of Nazareth,
he began to cry out and say,
"Jesus, son of David, have pity on me."

Mark goes on to say that after getting healed by Jesus, Bartimaeus followed the Lord 'in the way'(Verse 52, KJV).
In the narration of a number of Jesus' miracles, identity of the beneficiary is not given. That Mark mentions the identity of the blind beggar implies that he would subsequently become a household name among the followers of Christ. My question is : What do traditions say about the post- healing life of Bartimaeus, the blind beggar ?
